# Redirecting index.php to specific WordPress page in subdirectory but hide page url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect index.php (or default main domain page) to an specific WordPress page in the subdirectory of the same domain. But at the same time Hide the WordPress page's URL path (not show on the browser's address bar).

For example when users go to mywebsite.com it will redirect to 
`mywebsite.com/WPsite/WPpage` (NOT default WordPress home page).
But the address bar will say mywebsite.com

I'm using this on my .htaccess for the redirection

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ /WPsite/WPpage/
```

But I need to HIDE the "WPsite/WPpage/" part.

It doesn't have to be the .htaccess route only, if there's a php function that I can use in the index.php file that's fine too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put this at your main directory `.htaccess` file if you want to replace index directory to be for specific page :

```
DirectoryIndex   path/to/your/page.php
```

Comment: not working for wordpress page. Is it because wordpress pages are created on the fly and don't really have a .php file extension? I only get an "Index of/" page.

Comment: No it is working in wordpress , maybe there is something else

Comment: Will this path work? mywebsite.com/WPsite/WPpage.php or just the subdirectory WPsite/WPpage.php